# Can Amazon Comprehend extract and categorizing data from classifieds

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-comprehend

I have a large dataset from which I would like to extract and categorize specific elements. Below is a most common example:

[image]

I would like to know if this is possible using Amazon Comprehend or maybe there are better tools to do that. I am not a developer and looking to hire someone to program this for me. But I would like to understand conceptually if something like this feasible before I hire someone.

Answer (score 1):

Comprehend is capable of extracting and categorizing text from your document. You can use  Comprehend’s Custom Entity Recognition.

For this, you will provide annotated training data as input. You can leverage Ground Truth in Amazon SageMaker to do the annotations, and directly provide Ground Truth output to Comprehend Entity Recognition Training job. You can also provide your own annotations file for the training job - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/API_EntityRecognizerInputDataConfig.html.

The relevant APIs for Amazon Comprehend would be -

1. Training - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/API_CreateEntityRecognizer.html
2. Async Inference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/API_StartEntitiesDetectionJob.html
   OR
   Sync Inference Over Custom Endpoint -
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/API_CreateEntityRecognizer.html

Here is a detailed example of how to train custom entity recognizers with Amazon Comprehend - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/training-recognizers.html

Annotation file example for this use-case.

| File | Line | Begin Offset | End Offset | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| doc1 | 3 | 0 | 2 | Width |
| doc1 | 3 | 5 | 6 | Ratio |
| doc1 | 3 | 9 | 10 | Diameter |
| doc1 | 0 | 12 | 20 | Brand |
| doc1 | 0 | 6 | 6 | Quantity |
| doc1 | 6 | 8 | 10 | Price |
| doc1 | 1 | 20 | 22 | Condition |
| doc1 | 0 | 42 | 48 | Season |
| doc2 | 0 | 45 | 48 | Quantity |
| doc2 | 1 | 78 | 79 | Price |

The file doc1 should contain the text that you want to extract entities from.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. When providing an begin and end offset, that's just for model to learn, correct? Because in future, Type may not be on the same line and have the safe offset.

Comment: That's correct, the offsets are used for model training. Once the model is trained, inference can be performed on natural language documents. As a response, you will receive the text corresponding to entity types with the specific location within the document.